# Оптимизация disk utilization

Tags: linux, centos, hdd, raid

Поставил недавно munin и вижу вот такой график:

[image]

Диск - 2x 1tb 7.2k SFF SAS в raid 1. На сайте очень много мелких (5-10 кб) картинок, на каждой странице их по 20-30. Подскажите пожалуйста, как уменьшить загрузку диска? Ставить еще диски и переносить часть содержимого на них? или лучше систему на 1 диск, а картинки на другой?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать отдавать кешированные изображения, поставив varnish или squid. Ну соответственно лучше разнести систему и файлы которые отдаётся, чтобы система могла работать)Можно продвинуться дальше и хранить в какой нить tmpfs если памяти много

Comment: Если памяти много, то page cache сам должен забиться этими картинками.